# do While inside a variavel

Tags: php

Estou a criar um sistema de pesquisa por aonde o utilizador ira colocar somente o mês e o ano que pretende pesquisar.
mas não estou a conseguir o código é o seguinte

```
$output='<h2 class="text-center mb-4" style="color:red">Elementos</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">          
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="jumbotron">
                        <th>Nº Interno</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>SV</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                '.do{.' 
                    <tbody style="border-bottom:2px solid red;">
                        <td>'.$row_elementos['N Interno'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row_elementos['Nome'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$total.'</td>
                    </tbody>'.
                }while ($row_elementos = mysql_fetch_assoc($elementos)).'
            </table>
        </div>';
```

Depois é feito o print a base da pesquisa feito em baixo com o seguinte código

```
<?php print("$output");?>
```

os erros estão no {do(syntax error, unexpected 'do'(T_DO))} e no {while(syntax error, unexpected '}' }.
Como devo corrigir os erros?

Comment: Feche a string primeiro, depois faça um while normal.

Comment: como assim? o while é só feito naquele local

Comment: Ele quis dizer para fechar a string ali no thead e fazer o do while normal

Comment: mas isto é feito o print após uma pesquisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente concatenar por partes não misturar tudo num bolo. Exemplo:

```
$output='<h2 class="text-center mb-4" style="color:red">Elementos</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">          
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="jumbotron">
                    <th>Nº Interno</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>SV</th>
                </tr>
            </thead><tbody style="border-bottom:2px solid red;">';
            do{ 
                $output .= '<td>'.$row_elementos['N Interno'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row_elementos['Nome'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$total.'</td>';
            }while ($row_elementos = mysql_fetch_assoc($elementos));
$output .= '</tbody></table></div>';
```

Comment: obrigado! 100% funcional

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro feche a string, não é possível concatenar ela com um laço de repetição. Use um `while` convecional se usar o `do-while` no caso da consulta retornar vazia será gerado alguns undefined index porque não existem e porque a verificação é feita apenas no final do laço e não no inicio.

```
$output='<h2 class="text-center mb-4" style="color:red">Elementos</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">          
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="jumbotron">
                        <th>Nº Interno</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>SV</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>';

                while ($row_elementos = mysql_fetch_assoc($elementos)){
                    $output .= '<tbody style="border-bottom:2px solid red;">
                        <td>'.$row_elementos['N Interno'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row_elementos['Nome'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$total.'</td>
                    </tbody>';
                }   


            $output.= '</table></div>';
```

Comment: fica funcional mas não me apareceu o primeiro elemento

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos é para exibir todos o registros. Você use em algum outro lugar `$row_elementos` ou preenche ela manualmente?

Comment: como assim? não percebi